# What is mysql password if we install the mysql using shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu-12.04

I am writing the shell script to automatically install all the required packages for PHP site, I have written the script to automate the installation. I am using below script to install the mysql without prompt for password:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILEPATH=/home/philtracker/logs/logs.log
echo "Executing Installation script">>$LOGFILEPATH
for i in apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5  php5-json mysql-server apache2-mod-auth-mysql     php5-mysql
    do
        sudo apt-get -y install $i
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo "$i: installation failed for $i">>$LOGFILEPATH 2>&1
        else
            echo "$i: Installation successful for $i">>$LOGFILEPATH 2>&1
    fi
done
```

The above script installing the all packages successfully, But as I have automated the installation for MYSQL I don't have a password to login to mysql. Is there any default password set by MySQL ?

Comment: which specific version of mysql are you using?

Comment: on a fresh/clean install, the root account usually has no password.

Comment: I can do a trick using script to reset the password of root user but I want to check if there is any other alternative

Comment: I am using mysql 5.5.37 ubuntu version

Comment: If root account has no password is there any way to login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's root/root...or it's blank!

You can also directly update the password:

```
UPDATE
   mysql.user
SET
   Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
WHERE
   User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/15-practical-usages-of-mysqladmin-command-for-administering-mysql-server/

Comment: Yes, I can do this to reset the password, I have tried this and it works but I am thinking if I have any default password then I can skip change password. Both  root/root...or blank isn't working

Comment: For running above command I need to first login in to mysql and I can't as I don't have a password to log in

Comment: blank should be default - root/toor is only other immediate suggestion...let me ask my old dba.

Comment: thanks, It works It was my mistake I was using "mysql -uroot -p" instead of using "mysql -uroot" only.